# Retry in JMS MessageDriven Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I have a MessageDriven bean which consume messages and send it to somewhere else by REST API. Like this:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "n", activationConfig = {...})
public class SubmitMessageBean implements MessageListener {

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message) {
        try {
            // Submit data to somewhere with REST API
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.context.getRollbackOnly();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When error happens I want to retry sending in a minute. It there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. You can also easily add delay to give the remote system more time to resolve the error.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "n", activationConfig = {...})
public class SubmitMessageBean implements MessageListener {

   @Inject
   JMSContext context;

   @Resource(mappedName = "...")
   Queue queue;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        Integer retry = 0;
        try {
            // track how many time we tried before
            retry = message.getIntProperty("retry");

            // Submit data to somewhere with REST API
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Put it back in queue again
            // You can limit number of retry by keeping retry variable 
            if (retry < 5) {
                JMSProducer producer = this.context.createProducer();
                producer.setProperty("retry", r);
                // Add some delay to start it again after a minute
                producer.setDeliveryDelay(60000);
                // Send it again with send()
            }
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to fill {...} with your own right values.